# How to access a Novell network through System.DirectoryServices?

Tags: c#, .net, directoryservices, novell, edirectory

I'm accessing an ActiveDirectory through

```
    public static DirectoryEntry GetRootDSE()
    {
        DirectoryEntry rootDSE = new DirectoryEntry("LDAP://rootDSE");

        return rootDSE;
    }
```

Now I need to access a Novell network.

In [MSDN: System.DirectoryServices Namespace](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.directoryservices%28v=vs.71%29.aspx) it looks like I only have to change "LDAP:" to "NDS:" so, is it really this easy:

```
    public static DirectoryEntry GetRootDSE()
    {
        // changed LDAP:// to NDS://
        DirectoryEntry rootDSE = new DirectoryEntry("NDS://rootDSE");

        return rootDSE;
    }
```

or do if have to keep some other things in mind?

Would be nice if someone has some further information for my problem...

P.S.: I'm using .Net2.0

Answer (score 1):

First off, the ldap:// notation is somewhat AD specific, and assumes that the current box is the server, and the current user running this process will be the credentials used.

So for eDirectory, you probably want ldap://serverIp:port (389 or 636 for port).  Not sure what the user and password parameters are though.